How old is the character  biáng?
I was browsing Reddit just now, and stumbled upon this question:

What are the top 10 most recently created Chinese characters?

where one user replied:

I only know about  biáng, unfortunately, my typeface doesn't show it, so I see a square instead of a character.

Curious, I thought this was a fairly old character.  I'm quite unsure now though.  I found this image on the Chinese Wikipedia page:



which is captioned here as:

描述:  English: The rubbings of Biáng.  中文：“Biang”字拓片，小篆。
日期:  在1900年之前s

I'm not sure if this date applies to the rubbings, or what they are rubbings of.  So I don't know.
Question: How old is the character  biáng?

On the Wiki page you referenced there are number of origin stories, some dating as far back as the Qin dynasty. But there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer as to its etymology.

https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%F0%B1%9F%9B


How old is the character  biáng?

 
Pronunciation - biang or biangbiang
The exact age of this character is unknown, but it is believed that the character was created during Qin Dynasty. According to  BBC.com -
"It's unclear exactly how the complex biang character originated, but its creation is steeped in legend. One widely told story credits it to a young scholar from the Qin Dynasty (221-207 BC) who didn't have enough money for his bowl of biang biang noodles and offered to invent a character in lieu of payment."
The story was also echoed in this article with more details.
Note this character wasn't collected in any Chinese dictionaries, but was added by Unicode (U+30EDE) in 2020.
